# No se puede convertir implícitamente en 'Android.OS.bundle' - C#

Tags: c#, android, firebase, rest, post

Estoy intentando con `C#` realizar un `Post`, pero me da el siguiente error al apenas digitar el código.

Ni siquiera lo he ajustado a mi caso, simplemente lo pego tal cual lo muestra la documentacion y me da error, no entiendo por que. Me da la impresion que podria ser un simple paquete Nuget dando lata pero el Asistente de VS no me recomienda ningún Nuget faltante tampoco.

**Documentación de Firebase:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=es-419&fbclid=IwAR1Yv2CEdi18Hb1UhykSLtc9fKdw6n_rnz7ppum0ieNMIrU1k4mMwesDonE#c

```
// This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
                var registrationToken = "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN";

                // See documentation on defining a message payload.
                var message = new Message()
                {
                    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "score", "850" },
                        { "time", "2:45" },
                    },
                    Token = registrationToken,
                };

                // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
                // registration token.
                string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
                // Response is a message ID string.
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

Errores:

```
No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'system.collections.generic.dictionary string, string en Android.os.bundle
```

.

```
Message no continen una definicion para 'Token'.
```

.

```
'FirebaseMessaging' no contiene una definición para 'DefaultInstance'.
```

He intentado reescribirlo, he revisado los Nuget, pero no logro descifrarlo.

[image: Captura]

Comment: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'system.collections.generic.dictionary string, string en Android.os.bundle

Comment: intenta var message = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message(){ etc.. }

Comment: Nada amigo. No funciono. Y ya tengo el paquete de Firebase y Firebase.Messaging referenciado. -- using Firebase.Messaging; using Firebase; --

Comment: Cual es el tipo de Data?, cuales son las propiedades dentro de la clase Message?

Comment: El Body y el Title de tipo string; pero lo escribi tal cual la documentacion sin ajustarlo para tratar de detectar lo que causa el error actual y no lo veo.

Comment: Agreguè una respuesta pero te sugiero revisar la documentaciòn que indico en la respuesta, me parece mucho mejor que la de Google, los errores que tienes son relacionados a que faltan clases o no has definido uno o varios token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar el primer error

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
> 'system.collections.generic.dictionary string, string en
> Android.os.bundle

debes asegurar usar los siguientes import:

```
using System.Collections.Generic; //Dictionary
using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging; //Message ,
```

Para el error:

> Message no continen una definicion para 'Token'.

No estas definiendo un token, el texto indica que debes definirlo como valor para la variable `registrationToken`  :

```
var registrationToken = "<definir aquì REGISTRATION_TOKEN>";
```

En cuanto a el error:

> 'FirebaseMessaging' no contiene una definición para 'DefaultInstance'.

Me parece que no tienes un Nuget que es [Xamarin Firebase Messaging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=macos#add-the-xamarin-firebase-messaging-package)

---

Por cierto el envio del mensaje es muy importante que se realice dentro de un proceso asincrono.

La documentaciòn que te sugiero revisar es:

**[Remote Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=macos#add-the-xamarin-firebase-messaging-package)**

Te comparto tambièn este [ejemplo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/blob/2d0a1a5a1ba6e219f0418c9e8f7265b887aa8563/FirebaseAdmin/FirebaseAdmin.Snippets/FirebaseMessagingSnippets.cs#L157-L178):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging;

namespace FirebaseAdmin.Snippets
{
    internal class FirebaseMessagingSnippets
    {
        internal static async Task SendToTokenAsync()
        {
            // [START send_to_token]
            // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationToken = "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN";

            // See documentation on defining a message payload.
            var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "score", "850" },
                    { "time", "2:45" },
                },
                Token = registrationToken,
            };

            // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
            // registration token.
            string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
            // Response is a message ID string.
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
            // [END send_to_token]
        }

        internal static async Task SendToTopicAsync()
        {
            // [START send_to_topic]
            // The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
            var topic = "highScores";

            // See documentation on defining a message payload.
            var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "score", "850" },
                    { "time", "2:45" },
                },
                Topic = topic,
            };

            // Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
            string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
            // Response is a message ID string.
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
            // [END send_to_topic]
        }

        internal static async Task SendToConditionAsync()
        {
            // [START send_to_condition]
            // Define a condition which will send to devices which are subscribed
            // to either the Google stock or the tech industry topics.
            var condition = "'stock-GOOG' in topics || 'industry-tech' in topics";

            // See documentation on defining a message payload.
            var message = new Message()
            {
                Notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Title = "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
                    Body = "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.",
                },
                Condition = condition,
            };

            // Send a message to devices subscribed to the combination of topics
            // specified by the provided condition.
            string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
            // Response is a message ID string.
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
            // [END send_to_condition]
        }

        internal static async Task SendDryRunAsync()
        {
            var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "score", "850" },
                    { "time", "2:45" },
                },
                Token = "token",
            };

            // [START send_dry_run]
            // Send a message in the dry run mode.
            string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(
                message, dryRun: true);
            // Response is a message ID string.
            Console.WriteLine("Dry run successful: " + response);
            // [END send_dry_run]
        }

        internal static async Task SendAllAsync()
        {
            var registrationToken = "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN";
            // [START send_all]
            // Create a list containing up to 500 messages.
            var messages = new List<Message>()
            {
                new Message()
                {
                    Notification = new Notification()
                    {
                        Title = "Price drop",
                        Body = "5% off all electronics",
                    },
                    Token = registrationToken,
                },
                new Message()
                {
                    Notification = new Notification()
                    {
                        Title = "Price drop",
                        Body = "2% off all books",
                    },
                    Topic = "readers-club",
                },
            };

            var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAllAsync(messages);
            // See the BatchResponse reference documentation
            // for the contents of response.
            Console.WriteLine($"{response.SuccessCount} messages were sent successfully");
            // [END send_all]
        }

        internal static async Task SendMulticastAsync()
        {
            // [START send_multicast]
            // Create a list containing up to 500 registration tokens.
            // These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationTokens = new List<string>()
            {
                "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1",
                // ...
                "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n",
            };
            var message = new MulticastMessage()
            {
                Tokens = registrationTokens,
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "score", "850" },
                    { "time", "2:45" },
                },
            };

            var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendMulticastAsync(message);
            // See the BatchResponse reference documentation
            // for the contents of response.
            Console.WriteLine($"{response.SuccessCount} messages were sent successfully");
            // [END send_multicast]
        }

        internal static async Task SendMulticastAndHandleErrorsAsync()
        {
            // [START send_multicast_error]
            // These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationTokens = new List<string>()
            {
                "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1",
                // ...
                "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n",
            };
            var message = new MulticastMessage()
            {
                Tokens = registrationTokens,
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "score", "850" },
                    { "time", "2:45" },
                },
            };

            var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendMulticastAsync(message);
            if (response.FailureCount > 0)
            {
                var failedTokens = new List<string>();
                for (var i = 0; i < response.Responses.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!response.Responses[i].IsSuccess)
                    {
                        // The order of responses corresponds to the order of the registration tokens.
                        failedTokens.Add(registrationTokens[i]);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"List of tokens that caused failures: {failedTokens}");
            }

            // [END send_multicast_error]
        }

        internal static Message CreateAndroidMessage()
        {
            // [START android_message]
            var message = new Message
            {
                Android = new AndroidConfig()
                {
                    TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                    Priority = Priority.Normal,
                    Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                    {
                        Title = "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
                        Body = "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.",
                        Icon = "stock_ticker_update",
                        Color = "#f45342",
                    },
                },
                Topic = "industry-tech",
            };
            // [END android_message]
            return message;
        }

        internal static Message CreateAPNSMessage()
        {
            // [START apns_message]
            var message = new Message
            {
                Apns = new ApnsConfig()
                {
                    Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "apns-priority", "10" },
                    },
                    Aps = new Aps()
                    {
                        Alert = new ApsAlert()
                        {
                            Title = "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
                            Body = "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% "
                                + "on the day.",
                        },
                        Badge = 42,
                    },
                },
                Topic = "industry-tech",
            };
            // [END apns_message]
            return message;
        }

        internal static Message CreateWebpushMessage()
        {
            // [START webpush_message]
            var message = new Message
            {
                Webpush = new WebpushConfig()
                {
                    Notification = new WebpushNotification()
                    {
                        Title = "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
                        Body = "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.",
                        Icon = "https://my-server/icon.png",
                    },
                },
                Topic = "industry-tech",
            };
            // [END webpush_message]
            return message;
        }

        internal static Message CreateMultiPlatformsMessage()
        {
            // [START multi_platforms_message]
            var message = new Message
            {
                Notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Title = "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
                    Body = "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.",
                },
                Android = new AndroidConfig()
                {
                    TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                    Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                    {
                        Icon = "stock_ticker_update",
                        Color = "#f45342",
                    },
                },
                Apns = new ApnsConfig()
                {
                    Aps = new Aps()
                    {
                        Badge = 42,
                    },
                },
                Topic = "industry-tech",
            };
            // [END multi_platforms_message]
            return message;
        }

        internal static async Task SubscribeToTopicAsync(string topic)
        {
            // [START subscribe_to_topic]
            // These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationTokens = new List<string>()
            {
                "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1",
                // ...
                "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n",
            };

            // Subscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens to the
            // topic
            var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SubscribeToTopicAsync(
                registrationTokens, topic);
            // See the TopicManagementResponse reference documentation
            // for the contents of response.
            Console.WriteLine($"{response.SuccessCount} tokens were subscribed successfully");
            // [END subscribe_to_topic]
        }

        internal static async Task UnsubscribeFromTopicAsync(string topic)
        {
            // [START unsubscribe_from_topic]
            // These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationTokens = new List<string>()
            {
                "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1",
                // ...
                "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n",
            };

            // Unsubscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens from the
            // topic
            var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.UnsubscribeFromTopicAsync(
                registrationTokens, topic);
            // See the TopicManagementResponse reference documentation
            // for the contents of response.
            Console.WriteLine($"{response.SuccessCount} tokens were unsubscribed successfully");
            // [END unsubscribe_from_topic]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Todo se debia a este import -- using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging; -- y es que no habia instalado el paquete nuget: Firebase.Admin.Messaging. Al instalarlo se solvento el resto. Lo demas estaba bien. Ahora solo estoy obteniendo un response null, pero eso ya es otro tema. Lo revisare en otro post. Muchas gracias nuevamente. En ningun lado lei sobre ese Nuget y tenia rato pegado con ese error. Me salvaste.